# Vault server on Openshift - connection refused

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, openshift, hashicorp-vault

I wanted to use vault server to store secrets and deploy it on openshift.

I wrote this dockerfile, built the image and pushed it to the openshift registry and created a deployment from this image stream:

```
FROM vault:1.5.0
ADD *.hcl /etc/config.hcl

ENTRYPOINT ["vault", "server", "-config=/etc/config.hcl"]
```

Here is the config:

```
storage "file" {
  path = "/vault/data"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address="127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable=1
}

disable_mlock = true

api_addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
```

I created a route to the 8200 port. When I use the vault CLI from inside the vault-server pod it works fine, I can login, configure etc. When i use the openshift cli on my local computer to forward port 8200 to my local 8200 port I can also access the API.

The problem is I cannot access the API from anywhere outside the pod. The route fives me a 503 response and when trying via http://vault-server.namepsace.svc:8200 I get connection refused (using Spring Rest Template).

How can I configure Vault to also accept external traffic?

Comment: Can you share the output of `kubectl describe svc vault-server`

Answer (score 1):

Your `listener` block means you are only listening for connections from localhost. Change the `address` field to `0.0.0.0:8200` to listen on all interfaces:

```
listener "tcp" {
  address="0.0.0.0:8200"
}
```

And please don't forget to enable TLS as soon as you've got connectivity working.